# Using Stats component of Apache Solr, how can I get stats OR results based on stats of a group?

Tags: solr, statistics

Recently I used stats component of solr. I can do a `group by` and get stats for each group in the following solr request: 
`http://localhost/solr/quan/select?q=*:*&stats=true&stats.field=income&rows=0&indent=true&stats.facet=township`

In this case, solr will group by `township` and do stats on `income` of families for each township. However I want to get info of families in detail rather than stats if the number of families is less than 5 in a group. How can I get this kind of mixed response from solr?

I need to do solr query only once. Don't tell me that get the response from previous request and do queries again for the groups who have less than 5 families.

Thanks, 
Quan

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the AnalyticsComponent which support facting

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5302